# WatchKit App Scheme Warning Icon

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, xcode6.3

Xcode won't let me run my watchkit app. See screenshot.

I added my watchkit app using the standard New > Target > WatchKit App and disabled the Notification and Glance Scenes (I just want an app).

Has anyone experienced and resolved this?

[image]

Comment: What is the warning?

Comment: I can't see any. Nothing on hover, nothing on build.

Comment: Re-adding the targets including a Glance and Notification makes it work, but I'd rather not have both.

Answer (score 0):

You might forgot to add icons in Watch App `Images.xcassets` (Not watch Extension).

You might get more idea from attached image.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is it, because including Glance and Notifications when adding targets works.